# Javascript/AJAX wants to delete a html class from a guestbook entry

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

I'm writing a guestbook for my university project in JS and Ajax. I'm already able to post guestbook entries. Now my problem is that I don't know how to delete them again.

My PHP File looks like that

```html
<?php
###########################################################
/*
Developer:   Not Important
Version:    1.0
Release:    08.12.2014
*/
###########################################################

error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");

if ($_REQUEST["do"]=='add') {
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." SET date_time=now(), name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["name"])."', email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["email"])."', comment='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["comment"])."'";
 $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);

}

?>

</div>
<form id="GuestBookFrm" name="GuestBookFrm" onsubmit="return false;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><strong>Gästebuch Eintrag schreiben</strong></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="text" name="your_name" id="your_name" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kommentar</td>
    <td><label>
      <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="5"></textarea>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Senden" onclick="SubmitComment()" />
   <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

<div id="Comments">

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." ORDER BY id DESC";
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
 echo "<div><ul><li><h2>".stripslashes($row["name"])."</h2></li>";
 echo "<li><span>gepostet am ".$row["date_time"]."</span><a class=\"delete\" href=\"#\">Löschen</a> <a class=\"edit\" href=\"#\">Editieren</a></li>";
 echo "<li><p>".stripslashes(nl2br($row["comment"]))."</p></li></ul></div>";
}
?>
```

and my Javascript looks like that:

```js
var bustcachevar=1; //bust potential caching of external pages after initial request? (1=yes, 0=no)
var bustcacheparameter="";

function createRequestObject(){
 try {
  xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 } catch(e) {
  alert('Sorry, but your browser doesn\'t support XMLHttpRequest.');
 };
 return xmlhttp;
};

function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
 var page_request = createRequestObject();
 
 if (bustcachevar) bustcacheparameter=(url.indexOf("?")!=-1)? "&"+new Date().getTime() : "?"+new Date().getTime()
 page_request.open('GET', url+bustcacheparameter, true)
 page_request.send(null)

 page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
  loadpage(page_request, containerid)
 }

}

function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
 if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1)) {
     document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText;
 };
}


function LoadComments() {
 ajaxpage("guestbook.php", "GuestBook");
}

function SubmitComment() {
 if (document.GuestBookFrm.your_name.value !== '' && document.GuestBookFrm.email.value !== '' && document.GuestBookFrm.comment.value !== '') {
  ajaxpage("guestbook.php?do=add&name=" + encodeURI(document.GuestBookFrm.your_name.value) + "&email=" + encodeURI(document.GuestBookFrm.email.value) + "&comment=" + encodeURI(document.GuestBookFrm.comment.value), "GuestBook");
 } else {
  alert ("Fill in all fields.");
 }
 
}

LoadComments();
```

My SQL database looks very simple:

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guestbook` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
```

As you can see in my php file, there is a line

```
echo "<li><span>gepostet am ".$row["date_time"]."</span><a class=\"delete\" href=\"#\">Löschen</a> <a class=\"edit\" href=\"#\">Editieren</a></li>";
```

which has a delete and an edit button with a class "delete" and class "edit". Now I'm trying since days to make it work that I can delete the guestbook entries again. I don't need any confirmation if I want to delete or not. I just need to click on delete and then it should be gone.

Is there any code someone can provide to help me to make it work?

Best Regards

Comment: you search **DELETE** Statement http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: i think you need to create another case of if ($_REQUEST["do"]=='add') { for deleting, even the sql as @donald123 says

Comment: Mr. "Not Important", please stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use PDO / MySQLi instead

Answer (score 1):

Think in the steps your code needs to do for a delete:

1. You need to capture the click event on the delete button
2. On client code you need to send to your server an AJAX call to ask for deletion
3. On server code you need to identify this AJAX call, build a DELETE statement and execute it.
4. The result of the DELETE statement should return a result value to your client code
5. Depending on the response received, your client code should return a message warning about a deleting error OR erase the recently deleted element from page's DOM.

Try to separate each of this tasks and see if you know how to made each one of them. If you don't know how to do any of them or have problems with anyone in particular ask in this site for the specific problem.

I hope this helps.